# What is a good/safe way to dynamically save a username and password information in Java?

Tags: java

Ideally I would do this with environment variables however that is not an option for me right now. Is there some other way that I can dynamically save information such as the username and password? For the time being I am doing this

```
private final static String USER = "*****";
private final static String PASSWORD = "*******";
```

Comment: if you need the data to persist, write it to a file..

Comment: Don't save plain password, save its hashed version.

Comment: use a Data base or [java files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) with [input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newInputStream%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...%29) and [output](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newOutputStream%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...%29) streams

Comment: Are these credentials for users of the application, or credentials for an external resource (e.g. a database) used by the application?

Comment: Are you using a container (JBOSS, Glassfish, etc) for your application or is it a standalone java app (batch or swing)?

Comment: @NickJ They are for users of the application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to persist it. Hash it with a salt

this is a good reference to start:

https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#javasourcecode

you can choose to save it in a database or just plain file.